# Converting eval parse to json.parse

Tags: javascript, json

This pertains within a BPM application called ProcessMaker but the logic and syntax should relatively be the same. I'm trying to 
populate a grid (basically a table) from another serialized grid where the data has been passed to a hidden field.

The data passed to the hidden field is formatted as follows:

Ex:

```
{"1":{"id":"4332","product":"ball","price":"$5.00",”ordered":"On"}
```

The javascript example below found on processmaker's wiki unserializes the hidden field as an object and uses its information to populate a new grid named whatever it is. The example on processmaker's wiki uses the eval function but how would you convert this using the json.parse() function?

```
        function populateGrid() {
           var grd = getObject("newAccountsGrid");
           //remove all existing rows in the grid (except the first one): 
           var i = Number_Rows_Grid("newAccountsGrid", "accId");
           for (; i > 1; i--)
              grd.deleteGridRow(i, true);
           //The first row can't be deleted, so clear the fields in the first row:
           for (i = 0; i < grd.aFields.length; i++)
              getGridField("contactsGrid", 1, grd.aFields[i].sFieldName).value = "";
           //unserialize the hidden field as an object:
           var oAccounts = eval('(' + getField("sAccounts").value + ')'); 
           if (typeof oAccounts == 'object') { 
              for (var rowNo in oAccounts) {
                 if (rowNo != 1)
                    grd.addGridRow();
                 getGridField('newAccountsGrid', rowNo, 'accId').href = oAccounts[rowNo]["accountId"];
                 getGridField('newAccountsGrid', rowNo, 'accName').href = oAccounts[rowNo]["accountName"];
                 getGridField('newAccountsGrid', rowNo, 'createDate').href = oAccounts[rowNo]["created"];
              }
           }
        }
        populateGrid(); //execute when the DynaForm loads
```

Comment: Have you tried to read about `JSON.parse()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be as simple as:

```
var oAccounts = JSON.parse(getField("sAccounts").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval("("+something+")")` ⇒ `JSON.parse(something)`

Answer (score 0):

Just a few lines above this example (ProcessMaker wiki), is a note where  recommend using JSON.parse ().
Using your example, your code should be as follows:

```
    function populateGrid() {
   var grd = getObject("newAccountsGrid");
   //remove all existing rows in the grid (except the first one): 
   var i = Number_Rows_Grid("newAccountsGrid", "accId");
   for (; i > 1; i--)
      grd.deleteGridRow(i, true);
   //The first row can't be deleted, so clear the fields in the first row:
   for (i = 0; i < grd.aFields.length; i++)
      getGridField("contactsGrid", 1, grd.aFields[i].sFieldName).value = "";
   //unserialize the hidden field as an object:
   var oAccounts = JSON.parse(getField("sAccounts").value); 
   if (typeof oAccounts == 'object') { 
      for (var rowNo in oAccounts) {
         if (rowNo != 1)
            grd.addGridRow();
         getGridField('newAccountsGrid', rowNo, 'accId').href = oAccounts[rowNo]["accountId"];
         getGridField('newAccountsGrid', rowNo, 'accName').href = oAccounts[rowNo]["accountName"];
         getGridField('newAccountsGrid', rowNo, 'createDate').href = oAccounts[rowNo]["created"];
      }
   }
}
populateGrid(); //execute when the DynaForm loads
```